# When is "sex" sex, and when is it "gender"?

Tags: word-usage

There is a correction in today's edition of *The Guardian* - as follows:

> A report referred to an employment tribunal ruling about "sexual
> harassment". Such cases relate to behaviour of a sexual nature; this
> finding was that the harassment"related to the claimant's sex" (Insult
> referring to a man's baldness was sexual harassment, judges say, 14
> May, p14).

The correction does not indicate how such "harassment" might have been better described. Personally in any discussion of this kind where sexual issues are not involved, I would always play safe and use the word "gender". If, for example, a woman is not employed by an agricultural company,  because someone thinks women are not strong enough to lift heavy weights - that has nothing whatever to do with sex. And my own preference would be to call it "gender discrimination". Though the law in the UK has not recognised this and still, so far as I am aware talks of "sex discrimination".

In my view the word "sex" is, so far as possible, better left for matters sexual - and that in instances, such as in an application form, we do not ask for the applicant's
sex - but their "gender".

But I am interested here to discover any emerging practice across the English-speaking world here. Is there a movement towards restricting "sex" to that which the word immediately brings to mind and to leave the debate between men and women to matters of "gender"?

Comment: This will probably be closed as opinion-based, but I think it's interesting that in the Victorian era 'sex' _only_ meant 'gender', so expressions like 'the fairer sex' were used freely without any risk of embarrassment.

Comment: @KateBunting Yes I agree that it will likely be closed. As with  so many topics where there would be much profit in a discussion, the rule-book invariably gets brought out - almost childishly, I feel.

Comment: @KateBunting Your point about the Victorian "fairer sex" etc is well taken. The thing was that in the Victorian era the other meaning of "sex" was never talked about - not by respectable people anyway! Now that it is, we do need to make this important distinction I believe.

Comment: I remember a topic called "The opposite sex" in one of the English lessons when I was in high school, and the word "gender" was never used in any of those lessons. 20 years later I moved to the UK and I saw only "gender" on all the application forms, printed or online. Interesting question. Following...

Comment: ***Sex and gender: What is the difference?*** People often use the terms “sex” and “gender” interchangeably, but this is incorrect. Sex and gender are different, and it is crucial to understand why. https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/232363

Comment: That is what I meant when I referred to 'risk of embarrassment'! To the Victorians the word didn't automatically mean 'sexual intercourse', as it does today.

Comment: @KateBunting Or it could be something far less implicating - such as "a sexual glance". But it does get complicated when people at an employment tribunal talking about what is essentially a case of discrimination, start using terms like *sexual motives*.   There is also room for sinister ambiguity. A male employer turning down a female applicant for *sexual reasons* could simply mean that he unlawfully preferred to employ a man. But it could also suggest that he wouldn't employ her because she refused to go to bed with him.

Comment: The tldr of @user66974 's link is roughly "sex depends on X's and Y's and the likes, whereas gender depends on a person's self-identification". A question I see popping up more and more often though, is why one would include sex/gender on an application form at all, since it very often (not always) doesn't or shouldn't actually play any role.

Comment: @oerkelens As one who has done a fair amount of recruitment I would think that somewhat impractical. It's perhaps easy if you are employing a cleaner, or a cashier, but when fitting a person into a management job, you do need to have some understanding of the whole person. I don't believe we are yet living in such a gender-free world that male and female become irrelevant terms.

Comment: This question asks for observations on usage, it doesn't ask for opinions. Besides, the label "opinion-based" doesn't describe its intention correctly.

Comment: "Honey, this wine is so fantastic!"  "That's gin, dear."

Comment: [This](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/157866/which-is-more-correct-gender-or-sex) might help.

Comment: Also the [genderbread person](https://www.genderbread.org/).

Answer (score 8):

Until approximately half a century ago, the word *sex* was used both for sexual activity and for the the quality of being male or female. (In fact, as Ms. Bunting has pointed out in a comment, in the more distant past, the latter sense was the dominant one; the former topic was not supposed to be talked about at all, so there was no need to have a well established term for it.) The word *gender*, on the other hand, was before the 1970s used almost exclusively in the sense it has in grammar. Feminist literature then introduced *gender* as a technical term, with the meaning that was, in that theoretical context, different from the established meaning of *sex*, even though related to it. It should be noted that *gender* was not introduced in that literature as a replacement for *sex* (in the male-or-female sense), but as a term to be differentiated from it and used in addition to it. In that terminology, *gender* is used for for the qualities that a culture associates with being male or female, while *sex* is used for the purely biological characteristics.

The next development was that many people picked up that usage of *gender*, without paying full attention to its theoretical underpinnings, and started using it as a straightforward replacement for *sex* in the male-or-female sense. (One may speculate that the usage originated among those who were in their education exposed to the feminist literature that used *gender* in the technical sense, but who did not fully absorb what that sense was.) Presumably, what motivated the widespread use of *gender* in that way is that it made it possible to talk about being male or female, without triggering any associations with the sense that *sex* has in constructions such as *to have sex*. By the 1990s, that usage became fairly widespread and started pushing out the traditional use of *sex* for the quality of being male or female.

The development was given an additional impetus by the greater acceptance of the idea that human beings may not all be neatly classifiable as male or female, and that it is better to think of gender as a spectrum. While the articulations of that idea use *gender* in way that is consistent with its sense in the feminist literature, their currency probably also contributes to people using *gender* even when *sex* would be appropriate.

Whether that development is to be embraced or deplored is debatable. Some people may regret that it has made it more difficult to appreciate the theoretical point that feminist scholars tried to make by introducing the concept of gender, as something different from sex (rather than just a relabelling of it). Others may be glad that it has made it possible to more clearly separate the topics related to one's identity from the topics related to what sexual activities one engages in. Regardless of whether one approves or disapproves of that development, it seem that it is here to stay, and that an increasing number of people are now perceiving it as awkward when the word *sex* is used in the male-or-female sense.

There is, however, a component of this question that needs to be addressed separately. The OP wonders why the quoted article uses the word *sex* in the male-or-female sense, when many people would nowadays prefer to use *gender* for that purpose. Apart from any other reasons somebody may have for sticking with the traditional usage, it is crucial that the quoted article is a report on a legal case. The relevant laws have their roots in the era in which using *sex* for the quality of being male or female was standard. Because it is important that the continuity of the law be clearly visible, the legal arguments and rulings in this, as in many other areas, deliberately ignore the terminological changes that may occur in the society at large.

Comment: +1, and thank you for this considerable *opus*. It could perhaps, though. be further improved with some references.

Comment: The OED has - at the beginning of its Sense 3 of *gender* the following note: *Originally extended from the grammatical use at sense 1   (sometimes humorously), as also in Anglo-Norman and Old French. In the 20th cent., as sex came increasingly to mean sexual intercourse (see sex n.1 4b), gender began to replace it (in early use euphemistically) as the usual word for the biological grouping of males and females. It is now often merged with or coloured by sense 3b.*

Comment: Sense 1 is the linguistic use - to which you have referred and Sense 2, now obsolete, (and I hadn't previously been aware of this one) was for *A class of things or beings distinguished by having certain characteristics in common;*  This is clearly from the same root as *generic* - the adjectival sense.  Anyway your answer is on exactly the right lines.

Comment: This would be such an interesting post were there references to back up the information within it. Otherwise, it seems, this is just the impression you get. This is an important discussion and one which really warrants some evidence/references. I assume it's all accurate and correct and well-motivated, so there's presumably so many references and so much supporting evidence that could be called upon here.

Answer (score 2):

The question is based on a misapprehension, but the matter under discussion is sufficiently unclear that a clarification is needed. The original quotation from the *Guardian* is drawing a distinction between "sexual harassment" and "sex-based harassment".

**Sexual harassment** is "unwanted behaviour of a sexual nature", including talking about sex, unwanted flirting, sharing pornography, and touching someone against their will. (["Sexual harassment"](https://www.acas.org.uk/sexual-harassment), ACAS (UK), accessed 11 August 2022.)

**Sex-based harassment** is a larger category, covering all forms of harassment a person experiences because of their sex. It covers sexual harassment (including sexual violence), but also other negative actions and behaviours related to a person's sex: for instance insulting someone because they are a man, as well as physical violence directed at a particular sex. ([Sex-based harassment](https://www.hhs.gov/civil-rights/for-individuals/special-topics/harassment/index.html), U.S. Department of Health & Human Services, accessed 11 August 2022.)